# Issue with integrating GTM Lookup Tables for multi-environment setup

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have been working on integrating [GTM](https://www.google.com/analytics/tag-manager/) and [GA](https://www.google.com/analytics/#?modal_active=none) to my website, using Environment Variables to setup GA Property Views for different setups.

I found similar solutions in various blogs, i.e., by setting up [Lookup Tables](https://www.viryagroup.com/en/what-we-do/our-blog-posts/marketing-and-seo-blog/how-to-use-a-lookup-table-in-google-tag-manager-gtm-to-select-the-right-google-analytics-property) or [RegEx Table](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/the-regex-table-variable-in-google-tag-manager/), with lookups for GA-Tracking-ID.

**ISSUE**

Lookup Tables adds a prefix `vtp_` to the keys present in default GA-settings obj, as shown below:

[image: Default GA-Settings Object]

[image]

Due to this, GA doesn't work. 
*If I use the GA Settings Variable directly, Everything works fine.*

This happens on current Dashboard Setups for GTM and GA.

Comment: It would be useful to see more details on your setup: e.g. how are you referencing the lookup table in your GA variables setting? How is your lookup table setup? etc

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a Google Analytics Settings variable as the output of a Lookup Table variable for a simple reason:

The "Google Analytics Settings" field in a tag is the only place where you can use a Google Analytics Settings variable, and it is the **only** type of variable you can use there.

In other words, if you create a Lookup Table variable that returns Google Analytics Settings variables, there's no place to add that variable to, since the only valid place would be the Google Analytics Settings field which, as noted above, doesn't accept Lookup Table variables.

Trying to add the Lookup Table into the "Tracking ID" field, for example, is a mistake, since the table returns a Google Analytics Settings object rather than a valid tracking ID.

Comment: As mentionned by @Simo in his answer here : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/rU6z_3E3E84;context-place=forum/tag-manager

to achieve the same : 

You can use the one and the same GAS variable, just set the Tracking ID field in that variable to a Lookup that returns a different UA-XXXXX-Y depending on environment.

Answer (score 4):

i had the same issue, and i was mapping the lookup values to variables of type google analytics settings:

[image]

i changed them to strings then it started working:

[image]

Comment: Huh, this indeed worked, even though the variable version was showing up with the correct output in https://tagassistant.google.com.... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it successfully with Dev and Live environments setup.

1. **Enable `Environment Name` in Built-In Variables**

[image]

2. **Create a `Lookup Table` variable in User-Defined Variables as `GA Tracking ID - ENV`**

[image]

For the Lookup Table row, change it accordingly. In my case, my environments are only `Dev` and `Live` so I put it there.

3. **Create a `Google Analytics Settings` variable in User-Defined Variables**

[image]

For the `Track ID`, select the `GA Tracking ID - ENV` - that's all the variable config for this to work in minimum.

4. Then Create a Tag for the Google Analytics

[image]

Make sure to select the `Google Analytics Settings` created.